# Matrix exponential of a Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-mathematics, matrix-exponential, kronecker-product

I'm trying to find an expression for the matrix exponential of a Kronecker product of two matrices, $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{D}$. The matrix $\hat{c}$ is a small real and symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix:

$$
\hat{c} = \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & x \\ x & 0 \end{matrix}\right).
$$

The matrix $\hat{D}$ is either $512\times 512$ or $1024\times 1024$ and dense. I'd like to calculate the following:

$$
\exp\left(- i \delta \hat{c}\otimes \hat{D} \right).
$$

I am aware of the relationship between matrix exponentiation and the Kronecker sum:

$$
\exp\left(\hat{A}\oplus \hat{B}\right) = \exp\left(\hat{A}\right) \otimes \exp\left(\hat{B}\right).
$$

Does anyone have any experience in approaching problems like this?

Comment: Why are some matrices lowercase and others uppercase?

Comment: $$I\otimes\cos\left(\delta x D\right) -i\sigma_x\otimes\sin\left(\delta x D\right)$$